# Recursion Troubling me

Tags: java, recursion

I'm new to all this so.. thanks

Just curious why this won't work.

Its telling me that public int sumFirst(int n) is an illegal start to an expression.

```
package program8;
public class Program8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        public int sumFirst(int n) 
        {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            n = input.nextInt();
            if (n == 0)
                return 0;
            else
                return sumFirst(n-1) + sumFirst(n-2);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: You cannot have a method inside the main

Comment: ok so this has to be defined in a new file?

Comment: No, methods should be declared in class, not in other methods. You seem to already know how to place method in class since you placed `main` method correctly.

Comment: But here `illegal start to an expression` refers to fact that inside method you can't use any visibility modifiers like `public` since scope of method is limited only to its body and everything inside it is *local* like *local variables*, so using `public` here is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you are trying to define a method inside your main method which will not work; Methods can only be defined at a class level.

Secondly, `n = input.nextInt();` inside the `sumFirst` method will be executed for each recursion, which is probably not what you want.

Try this instead:

```
public class Program8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(sumFirst(input.nextInt())); 
    }

    public int sumFirst(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return sumFirst(n-1) + sumFirst(n-2);
        }
    }
}
```